# CRON: Module is unknown

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, cron

I just upgraded our server to Ubuntu 10.04 and `cron` just stopped working. I tried to restart the server, restart `cron` but nothing worked for me. It just reports in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
May 12 16:32:01 uhor CRON[8424]: Module is unknown
May 12 16:33:01 uhor CRON[8430]: Module is unknown
May 12 16:33:01 uhor CRON[8429]: Module is unknown
May 12 16:34:01 uhor CRON[8432]: Module is unknown
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong? Some people were reporting also `Module is unknown` error after upgrading but it was usually with `passwd` command, not with `cron`.

Thanks :)

Edit: this is my /etc/pam.d/cron

```
#
# The PAM configuration file for the cron daemon
#

@include common-auth

# Read environment variables from pam_env's default files, /etc/environment
# and /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session       required   pam_env.so

# In addition, read system locale information
session       required   pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale

@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
# Sets up user limits, please define limits for cron tasks
# through /etc/security/limits.conf
# session    required   pam_limits.so
```

Answer (score 5):

Read this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/790538

The solution is to restart cron: /etc/init.d/cron restart

At least it worked on my servers.

Comment: Indeed, but that bug is newer than @Martin's issue! ;-)

Comment: I ran upgrade today but it didn't help. Still `Module is unknown` ...

Answer (score 2):

This is PAM related. Try:

```
aptitude reinstall libpam-modules libpam0g cron
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice but it didn't help. Still reporting just:
May 12 17:01:01 uhor CRON[9342]: Module is unknown

Comment: Anything weird in "/etc/pam.d/cron", does that file exist or do the modules mentioned in that file exist on the system in "/lib/security/"?

Comment: Here's another one to try: "sudo pam-auth-update --force"

Comment: Maybe that's it. My "/lib/security/" contains only 10 *.so files and "pam_env.so" or "pam_limits.so" are not among them. I have no idea where did they go.

Comment: Well... that explains the message "Module is unknown"! The pam_env.so is nowhere to be found on your system, not even with "locate pam_env.so"? On Ubuntu it's installed with package "libpam-modules", but that's what I suggested in my answer...